# Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently

Tags: java, android, bitmap

There is a good link on how to load large Bitmaps efficiently, so that you don't get an OutOfMemory-Error. 
Here ist the link: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html 
But my problem is, that I am a very newbie and I don't know how to understand the link. Could you please help me and modify my codes?

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:onClick="Menue"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="100"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/pfeilrechts" 
        android:onClick="Picture2"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

JAVA-Code:

```
package com.example.xxx;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class PictureOne extends Activity {

    public ImageView iv;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pictureone);

iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);}

{

ImageView.setImageBitmap(
        decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.id.imageView2, 100, 100));}

public void Picture2 (View view){
    Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);             
        startActivity(i);}}
```

Comment: Add the code where you load a file or resource in the imageview.

Comment: the examples in the linked page are runnable.  what do you need help understanding?

Comment: There are four different codes. Do I have to use all of them? In the same order?

Comment: You edited it? You only added one line. You can use a lot of code from your link. Start with the last one. Then add the function you called and so on. Edit your code here.

Comment: I edited it, but I am not sure if I got you right. I added the last code. My purpose it is do have different activities with Images and I want to Switch between These activities. But after a time I run out of Memory, because the Images are too large.

Comment: You might like this one https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader